# Hide divs on click - multiple boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a bit long info submission form. I have an option that someone click "add another", there is a notification box display with text like "Success!" like that with close button. Please check this image.

[image]

Therefore I have three "add another" buttons and three success alerts. When someone click close, that alert message needs to be disappear.

**The problem**

I used javascript for that success box. It does these things.

> Click "Add another" button, appears success box. 
>  Click close button on
>   success box, box disappears.

Here is my code.

```js
document.querySelector(".add-box").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector(".add-box-wrap").style.display = "inline-block";
});

document.querySelector(".add-box1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector(".add-box-wrap1").style.display = "inline-block";
});

document.querySelector(".add-box2").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector(".add-box-wrap2").style.display = "inline-block";
});


$(".claim-btn-close").click(function() {
  $(".add-box-wrap").hide();
});

$(".claim-btn-close1").click(function() {
  $(".add-box-wrap1").hide();
});

$(".claim-btn-close2").click(function() {
  $(".add-box-wrap2").hide();
});

<!-- This goes end of html page -->
function hide(target) {
  document.getElementsByClassName(target).style.display = 'none';
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Success form-->
<div class="add-box-wrap">
  <div class="claim-btn-close" onclick="hide('.claim-btn-close')">
    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <a href="" class="btn btn-primary claim-btn">Success!</a>
</div>

<!--Add another button -->
<div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12 no-padding">
  <a class="add-box">Add another<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
</div>
```

See.. there is a major problem with code repeating. (I didn't repeat html codes, just post here one example) I would like to know the best practice to achieve things like this.

Comment: i think you can put custom attribute to your html elements idx=1, idx=2 and so on, so as a button is clicked, you get its index, and use it to find html with those index to be hide.

Comment: dumb question,but, what is the difference between success form from `add-box` and `add-box1` and so on - a text, a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **displaying** the notification box without repeating the code, one of the way is you could make use of `data` attributes. Change the `data` attribute for all the buttons and let the class `.add-box` be the same. like so:

```
<div class="add-box-wrap1" style="display: none;">
  <div class="claim-btn-close">
    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <a href="" class="btn btn-primary claim-btn">Success!</a>
</div>
<div class="add-box-wrap2" style="display: none;">
  <div class="claim-btn-close">
    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <a href="" class="btn btn-primary claim-btn">Success!</a>
</div>

<!--Add another button -->
<div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12 no-padding">
  <a class="add-box" data-target="1">Add another<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
</div>

<!--Add another button -->
<div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12 no-padding">
  <a class="add-box" data-target="2">Add another<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
</div>
```

And change your Jquery to just **one function**.

```
$(".add-box").click(function() {
  $(".add-box-wrap" + $(this).data('target')).show(); //.add-box-wrap1 or .add-box-wrap2 
});
```

**Explanation of the above line:** It just means we are getting the value of the "clicked" button's `data-target` value(which is 1 or 2) AND **appending** that value to the "add-box-wrap"(which will be `add-box-wrap1` or `add-box-wrap2`) to search for that element to display it using `.show()`.

> Using `show()` or `.css` jquery functions is upto you. But I suggest not to mix both vanilla JS and JQuery codes(like in your question).

**Closing**

You can simply use `closest` or `parent`, like so:

```
$(".claim-btn-close").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

```js
$(".add-box").click(function() {
  $(".add-box-wrap" + $(this).data('target')).show();
});

$(".claim-btn-close").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="add-box-wrap1" style="display: none;">
  <div class="claim-btn-close">
    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <a href="" class="btn btn-primary claim-btn">Success!</a>
</div>
<div class="add-box-wrap2" style="display: none;">
  <div class="claim-btn-close">
    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <a href="" class="btn btn-primary claim-btn">Success!</a>
</div>

<!--Add another button -->
<div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12 no-padding">
  <a class="add-box" data-target="1">Add another<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a> 
</div>

<!--Add another button -->
<div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12 no-padding">
  <a class="add-box" data-target="2">Add another<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
</div>
```

**Update on another question(3 column):**

Using bootstrap, you can wrap the `add-box-wrap` divs within a `.row` and give each of it a class like **col-*-4**(`class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"`) assuming you have 3 success buttons(12/3 = 4). So the first part of your html would become

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="add-box-wrap1 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="display: none;">
    <div class="claim-btn-close">
      <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary claim-btn">Success!</a>
  </div>
  <div class="add-box-wrap2 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="display: none;">
    <div class="claim-btn-close">
      <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary claim-btn">Success!</a>
  </div>
  <div class="add-box-wrap3 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="display: none;">
    <div class="claim-btn-close">
      <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary claim-btn">Success!</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Then how to reduse repeat with "add another" thing?

Comment: You don't have to write another function. That one function(`$(".add-box").click(function`) handles all. Let me add more "add more buttons" to my answer

Comment: Now i have added 2 "add buttons" & "alert boxes" but you will require only that one `$(".add-box").click(function` instead of 2 click functions(as in your question)

Comment: Thanks! Let me try this.

Comment: Sure let me know if you face any issues. replace all your `hide` & `addEventListener` & `click` functions with this. Also add the `display: none;` to your `add-box-wrap`s

Comment: What is this meaning $(".add-box-wrap1" + $(this).data('target')).show(); //.add-box-wrap1 or .add-box-wrap2 ?

Comment: Works like charm! Thanks a lot. I have another question related to this. Are you able to answer that also? I'll start new question.

Comment: Sure, i can try. Maybe you can mention me so I get a notification.

Comment: Nice! Think this way, If I have another form on another page with exact same process. Then how do I use your code?

Comment: Just make sure the script file containing the above code is being called on that page as well. It should work without any extra code, assuming all the class names are same.

Comment: Cheers .. let me know if you have another question.

Comment: Ah you just like javascript ninja. If I want to add another "success!" box right side to that box. What should we do? http://i64.tinypic.com/2im50uq.png

Comment: Do you mean, add multiple success box(next to each other) on only **one button click**?

Comment: No multiple clicks. Max 3 boxes

Comment: Ok .. are you using bootstrap or any other grid framework?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Check & let me know. Its only html change.

Comment: @CssSY - did you add `col-md-4` to every button's parent div ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use DOM relationship to target the desired element. Bind event handlers using a common class then use `.closest()` to traverse up desired element.

```
$(".claim-btn-close").click(function(){
    $(this).closest(".add-box-wrap").hide();
});
```

If element are dynamically generate use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) approach.

```
$(staticParentElemet).on('click',".claim-btn-close",function(){
    $(this).closest(".add-box-wrap").hide();
});
```

Comment: How can I apply for those 3 boxes?

Comment: @CssSY Add `claim-btn-close` to all the buttons and it will attach event handler with them

Comment: Then how to reduse repeat with "add another" thing?